# In Cypher can I check if a property is a list before updating its value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are updating data in a database and for some nodes, because of legacy data, we might find a property as a string or as a list. I would like to convert strings into an empty list and keep lists as is.
I have tried something like this :

> MATCH (a:part) WHERE NOT EXISTS((a.serials)[0]) SET a.serials=[] return a

but it just throws an error.

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypher has no built-in function for this but there is a small hack you can use that is checking if adding an element to the property would increase its size by 1 , for eg

```
MATCH (n:Award)
RETURN size(n.years + 11) = size(n.years)+1 AS isList
```

`+` sign, add elements, concat or sums. Therefore to differentiate a a string from an array, we need to add two digits.

---

**UPDATE FOR NEO4J5**

Neo4j 5.10 introduced type predicate expressions for list types, example :

```
CREATE (n:Node {id: 1}) SET n.roles = ['roleA', 'roleB']
RETURN n.roles IS :: LIST<ANY>
```

More information here : https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/values-and-types/type-predicate/#type-predicate-lists

Comment: Almost there ! But very interesting trick !
MATCH (n:Award)
RETURN size(n.years + 11) = size(n.years)+1 AS isList

Comment: @YoannMaingon I added an example for Neo4j 5 now :D

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the APOC library to inspect a property type:

```
MATCH (a:part) 
WHERE NOT  apoc.meta.isType(a.serials) = "LIST"
SET a.serials=[] 
return a
```

You can check the docs for more info: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.meta/apoc.meta.isType/

Comment: we were looking for something without APOC but I don't think we'll get anything. Therefore I check it as the correct answer !